# Exit Criteria Not exiting subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, unsubscribe

I have set up a journey where I am using Salesforce Data entry source, with lead ID coming in from my Campaign(in sales cloud) that I have set up for this journey. I have set up decision splits where after a wait activity, the split checks the contact data(through synced lead obj) to see if "emailoptout" not true. If "emailoptout" is true, it is supposed to send them down the path to exit the journey. If not true, they are supposed to continue journey and receive a reminder email. I have seen so many different answers for exit criteria, and SF itself doesn't have the best documentation on the different procedures for Exit Criteria.

I have looked through this link https://deepwhydesign.medium.com/salesforce-obscura-salesforce-marketing-cloud-no-exit-from-the-journey-ad3cc4b5038f , and have found that this might be the best option to solve my case. The biggest issue is, we don't want to sync all our leads into MC and take up so much of our contact allotment and it seems we need to make our "Copy" of the synced data to check on things.

In this scenario, do I need to create that copy of the synced data, or am I able to reference my Sales Cloud to check to see if there has been a change in the "emailoptout" field and exit my subscribers on that notion?

Thanks for any help! I have included below a picture of my Data Entry event.[image]

Comment: You'll need that lead to pulled into the synched DE in order to see the record in the decision split.  You can limit the number of leads that you synch by either a date or creating/using a boolean field on the lead record.  Would it be possible on the CRM side to flag a field on the lead when they are dropped into the campaign?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have specific steps for emailoptout = true entries in the journey? (e.g. send SMS or update SF record), or you just want them to exit the journey with no interactions? What activities are defined before the wait? and how long is the wait, if a long wait is required you may want to check Lead emailOptOut status assume during that period they may update emailOptOut status in CRM?

If you don't have specific activities for those emailOptout entires, you can add Lead:EmailOptOut=false to entry criteria, so they don't need to enter into the journey at all.